# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID

Tags: c#, com-interop

I am using VB6 DLL in ASP.Net web site, when I add the reference of VB6 DLL it got added as a Interop.X.DLL and it compiled and executed properly. But when I published the website on Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6.0 and executed it gives the error 
"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {82EA3A98-AD80-4250-9EEF-5B8001F65091} failed due to the following error: 80040154"

I have not registered the interop.X.DLL on Windows Server 2003.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you deploy and register the actual VB6 dll properly on the server?

Comment: Yes, still it is giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM error 80040154 indicates that your COM component hasn't been properly registered.

A typical problem is that IIS usually runs under a different account. Check the Registry using regedit.exe and make sure the registration is present in the following key:

```
HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\{your guid}
```

and not in HKCU or HKCR only. If it is not present, re-register the COM component with regsvr32 using an administrator account.

Should you be running on an x64 edition of Windows Server, make sure that you select the 32-bit version of regsvr32 under C:\Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got the problem resolved, I found that the COM+ Event System and Remote Procedure Call Service were not started for the logged in user.